# PHP/MySQL between day and day+1d7h

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, between

I m trying to execute this query into my php file but does not return any results (no errors)

```
$day = $_GET["day"];    
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE TIMESTAMP('date','time') BETWEEN '$day 07:01:00' AND DATE_ADD('$day',INTERVAL '1 7' DAY_HOUR) ORDER BY kod";
display_db_query($query_string, $connection, $header_bool, $table_params);

//date format: yyyy-mm-dd
//time format: hh:mm:ss
```

Can anyone help? Is there any wrong into the $query_string?

Here is the display_db_query code:

```
function display_db_query($query_string, $connection, $header_bool, $table_params) {
    // perform the database query
    $result_id = mysql_query($query_string, $connection)
    or die("display_db_query:" . mysql_error());
    // find out the number of columns in result
    $column_count = mysql_num_fields($result_id)
    or die("display_db_query:" . mysql_error());
    // Here the table attributes from the $table_params variable are added
    print("<TABLE $table_params >\n");
    // optionally print a bold header at top of table
    if($header_bool) {
        print("<TR>");
        for($column_num = 0; $column_num < $column_count; $column_num++) {
            $field_name = mysql_field_name($result_id, $column_num);
            print("<TH>$field_name</TH>");
        }
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
    // print the body of the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_id)) {
        print("<TR ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>");
        for($column_num = 0; $column_num < $column_count; $column_num++) {
            print("<TD>$row[$column_num]</TD>\n");
        }
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
    print("</TABLE>\n"); 
}
```

When i execute manually the query:

```
SELECT * FROM stats_temp WHERE TIMESTAMP('date','time') BETWEEN '2013-04-28 07:01:00' AND DATE_ADD('2013-04-28 00:00:00',INTERVAL '1 7' DAY_HOUR) ORDER BY kod
```

It returns 0 results.

When i execute manually the query without DATE_ADD but manual calc:

```
SELECT * FROM stats_temp WHERE TIMESTAMP('date','time') BETWEEN '2013-04-28 07:01:00' AND '2013-04-29 07:00:00' ORDER BY kod
```

It returns 0 results too that is impossible because there are data with this criteria.

The format of data are correct, so the problem is in TIMESTAMP('date','time'). Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you actually execute the query? I see only assignment here...

Comment: Also, your day is a number 2013 minus 4 minus 28, add quotes to make it a string.

Comment: No errors? When your day should clearly be a string?

Comment: actually, $day = $_GET["day"]. So no problem with this! The problem is into the $query_string, that's why i didnt post the execution code

Comment: @zuperakos Can you show us `display_db_query`?

Comment: @DarylGill please see the first post, i added it

Comment: Is `$connection` globally assigned so your query can use the connection variables?

Comment: @DarylGill yeah. When i send whatever other query it works.

Comment: @zuperakos please issue: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php    add that accordingly to your function to print out any errors, turn error reporting on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: errors: 0: . Also error_reporting is on apache "E_ALL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem was indeed into query_string, so i tried to re-write it. Here is the working query:

```
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM $tablename 
    WHERE CONCAT(date,' ',time) > '$day 07:00' AND 
    CONCAT(date,' ',time) < DATE_ADD('$day 06:59',INTERVAL '1' DAY)
    ORDER BY kod";
```